# Prism.Unity.Wpf problem: UnityServiceLocatorAdapter is missing after update

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

After updating **Prism** in a WPF application from version 7.2.0.1422 to version 8.0.0.1909, the **GetInstance** method no longer works:
CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance
The message is issued: “ServiceLocationProvider must be set”
I found that version 8 was missing the Prism.Unity.Wpf.**UnityServiceLocatorAdapter** class which was present in version 7 and which provided the ServiceLocator to work.
Q: How do I now take advantage of the CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Fundamentally, you and Prism shouldn't need to know anything about `CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance`.

Answer (score 5):

The [release notes](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v8.0.0.1909) of Prism 8.0 state a breaking change:

> Added ContainerLocator (NOTE: This replaces the Common Service Locator in Prism.Wpf)

So, with Prism 8, you write

```
Prism.Ioc.ContainerLocator.Container
```

if you absolutely have to access the container...

Comment: Thank you. Your advice helped me indeed. 
Now, instead of
`_eventAggregator = CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance <IEventAggregator> ();`
I do a call:
`_eventAggregator = (IEventAggregator) Prism.Ioc.ContainerLocator.Container.Resolve (typeof (IEventAggregator));`

and it works!
It is a pity that the old option has been removed. It was more laconic and versatile.

Comment: There _should_ be a generic variant of `Resolve` anyway, perhaps you're missing out on an extension method?

Comment: adding using Prism.Ioc; should solve the problem