# Prism: Inject service in a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, prism

I have three classes:

- MyModel (pure POCO object)
- MyModelWrapper (inherits from BindableBase)
- MyViewModel (it also inherits from Bindable class)

The problem I have is that I need a paremeterless constructor in MyModelWrapper because I bind an object in MyViewModel which is an `ObservableCollection<MyModelWrapper>` to a Datagrid Itemssource, and if it has not a parameterless constructor, you are not able to insert new rows in it (it does not appear a blank line at the end of the Datagrid).

So, if I want the user can insert new rows I need a parameterless constructor (and I do want).

And here I have my problem: **I need to inject a service** in MyModelWrapper.

I can inject the service in the constructor:

```
IMyModelWrapperService Service;
public MyModelWrapper(IMyModelWrapperService Service)
{
    Service = service;
}
```

But this way the Datagrid does not let the user to insert new rows.

If I could get a reference to the container, I could do `container.Resolve<IMyModelWrapper>()`, but I think that I would need to inject the container via constructor too, so it is not a valid solution.

So, I would need something like:

```
[Inject]
IMyModelWrapperService Service;
```

But I think property injection does not work in Prism (at least I am not able to use it).

Which is the right approach to inject a service in a class that needs to be parameterless in Prism?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely have to, you can access the container through `Prism.Ioc.ContainerLocator.Container` to get what you need.

Yes, this is evil and ugly, but if you need a dependency in a class whose construction you can't control, then this is your only option.

This is nearly a duplicate of [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64888503/5758420).

Comment: Yes, it works. I just needed to add `using Prism.Ioc;`. Without that `container.Resolve<IMyModelWrapperService>();` throws a quite strange exception: "The non-generic type-or-method 'identifier' cannot be used with type arguments."